# $n \cdot \arctan(\frac 1n)$ divergent or convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I tried to determine if $n\cdot \arctan (\frac 1n)$ is divergent or convergent.

My solution is in the two pictures. I really have no clue as how to solve it, so I tried something, but it cannot be right. At least that's what I think.

I am sorry in advance for my bad maths.

Appreciate all help :)[image]

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for the convergence of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}c_n$ or the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty c_n$?

Answer (score 1):

$$n\arctan\left(\dfrac1n\right) = \dfrac{\arctan\left(\dfrac1n\right)}{\dfrac1n} = \dfrac{\arctan\left(t\right)}{t} =\dfrac{\arctan\left(t\right) - \arctan 0}{t-0} $$
if $t:=1/n$.
This last expression tends to $\arctan'(0)=\dfrac1{1+0^2}=1$.

Thus, the series $\displaystyle \sum n\arctan\left(\dfrac1n\right)$ is divergent since its general term doesn't tend to 0.

Comment: The question was about the sequence, not the series with the sequence as its terms. You shown that that converges.

Comment: You're right, the question isn't clear! I began to assume the OP wanted to study the convergence of the sequence and rereading the question, I had a doubt and I included something for the series.

Answer (score 1):

If we speak about the sequence
$$a_n=n \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$  let $x=\frac{1}{n}$ and consider
$$y=\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left({x}\right)}x$$ and use Taylor series of $\tan ^{-1}\left({x}\right)$ close to $x=0$. Then
$$y=\frac 1x \left(x-\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^5\right) \right)=1-\frac{x^2}{3}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ So, back to $n$,
$$a_n=1-\frac{1}{3 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

From

$$1-x^2\le\frac1{1+x^2}\le1$$ you draw, by integration from $0$

$$x-\frac{x^3}3\le\arctan x\le x$$ and for $x>0$

$$1-\frac{x^2}3<\frac{\arctan x}x<1.$$

[image]

Comment: @Narasimham: thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The $n$th term doesn't go to zero, so the series diverges.

Comment: The question doesn't mention a series at all.

Comment: @robjohn I wondered whether he was talking about the sequence or the series too, but If you look at the pages the OP attached, he's clearly working with the series.

Comment: "our only aim is to test the convergence or divergence of $c_n$"

Comment: @robjohn Did you look at the attached pages?

Comment: That is what I was quoting from. The series in those pages is the series for arctan, not the series for $\sum\limits_nc_n$.

Comment: I have asked for clarification in a comment.